# Get real range in colormap with LogLocator

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

The following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import ticker

n = 50
A = np.tile(np.linspace(-26,-2,n),(n,1))
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(A)
plt.colorbar()

B = np.tile(np.logspace(-26,-2,n),(n,1))
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(B,locator=ticker.LogLocator())
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

produces these two plots:
[image]
[image]

For the linear case (first image), every color in the colorbar is present in the image, and the min and max values of A lie respectively in the first and last color bin (going bottom to top).

For the log case (second image), the colorbar's min and max values don't make sense to me anymore.
The minimum of B is 10^-26, so this value lies at the border between the first and second color bin of the colormap, but there are none of these two first colors in the image.
The maximum of B is 10^-2, and it lies at the border between the before-before last, and the before last color bins, so it could be considered in either.
But then, why is the last (yellow) color bin here, especially since there is no yellow in the image ?

So I find the default behavior of the colormap limits (for the LogLocator) weird because it is not representative of the real (or at least approximate) data range (like in the linear case), and it adds color bins (in this case 3 : 2 below the min, and 1 above the max) that are not present in the image.

Is this a bug or is there something I didn't understand ?

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer below gives the output that I want, but it just feels like I shouldn't have to do this and that I can expect the same behavior from the colormap with linear values, and from the LogLocator color mapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have specific intervals in your contour plot you would need to decide for them and supply them to the contouring function via the `levels` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import ticker

n = 50
A = np.tile(np.logspace(-26,-2,n),(n,1))
levels = 10.**np.arange(-26,-1,4)
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(A,levels=levels, locator=ticker.LogLocator())
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit lost on what the desired outcome is. If the automatic ticks are not what you're looking for you need to use custom ones.

Comment: I reedited my question (a lot), I hope it will be clearer :)

Comment: So the aim is to write a custom `Locator` that chooses the bins that a linear `AutoLocator` would choose for 10 to the data?

Comment: It's more to write a custom `Locator` that chooses the bins that a linear `AutoLocator` would choose for log10 of the data.
I would expect the default behavior of the LogLocator to basically plot `plt.contourf(np.log10(B))`, but with the labels of ticks being 10^x instead of x.